# In Dart / IntelliJ Idea how to make it an error when you miss a return?

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, flutter

In Dart / IntelliJ Idea how to make it an error (not a simple warning) when you miss a return?

If I forget to add a return, it's a simple warning, it's very easy to miss, and this makes me waste a lot of time.

```
warning: This function declares a return type of 'RichText', but doesn't end with a return statement.
```

Also, if the function has a return parameter, I don't see how it's not an error simply not returning anything (at least in Flutter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab a copy of the default `analysis_options.yaml` from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/analysis_options.yaml). Put it in the top folder of your flutter project (next to `pubspec.yaml`). Change line 31 to:

```
    missing_return: error
```

Beware of this [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28233).